# multi factor authentication server did not connect Azure LDAP through public IP

Tags: azure, ldap

Let me pass my question very simple.

I have tried Azure Domain services access through public IP configured. I have issue accessing through multi factor auth server from remote computer. I have checked the port is 636 is opened.

I have confirmed through LDAP browser. it is working nicely. but I couldnt connect through MFAS tool. it shows error "error connecting to LDAP: The server is not operational"
I have tried both DNS and public IP. both got failed in MFAS, but it is working in LDAP browser. did double check from Azure VM also. but in Azure VM, DNS method is working, not in public IP. No network security group is added.

connection method tried: SSL, simple and windows. none of the method got work in public IP

What is the issue would be? MFAS tool check anything specifically to locate LDAP server? I didnt get much help any forum regards this.

Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: Do you open port on Windows Firewall? For test, you could try to disable Windows Firewall.

Comment: Hi.. 
which port number to be opened? since the service running on Azure AD with SSL 636 port, that already opened and tested it is opened.

in there any other port that mulitfactor auth server required to open in Azure AD?

I have tried with Nework Security Group in Azure to opened the port and removed the NSG and tried. both scenario it is working on LDAP browser, but not in Multifact auth server tool.. :(

any knowledge to be known in MFAS too, side?